# Trying to start an app after build, but getting "router initialize error". How to fix it?

Tags: go, revel

This is what i get in terminal, looks like problem in first hook, but what's that?
Same app is working fine if just use revel run, but for some reason, when i try execute builded .exe i got that error((

```
INFO  16:56:12  revel revel_logger.go:29: There is 7 hooks need to run ...          section=server
INFO  16:56:12  revel revel_logger.go:29: Run the 1 hook ...                        section=util
panic: init: router initialize error [recovered]
        panic: Fatal error in startup


goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/revel/revel.Run.func1()
        C:/Users/User/go/pkg/mod/github.com/revel/revel@v1.0.0/server.go:70 +0xcf
panic({0xcd9f80, 0xc0004cfbf0})
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/panic.go:838 +0x207
github.com/revel/revel/logger.(*RevelLogger).Panic(0xc0004ec040?, {0xddff4b, 0x1d}, {0xc0004e64e0?, 0xc00019e300?, 0xc00049ce58?})
        C:/Users/User/go/pkg/mod/github.com/revel/revel@v1.0.0/logger/revel_logger.go:66 +0x4e
github.com/revel/revel.init.5.func1()
        C:/Users/User/go/pkg/mod/github.com/revel/revel@v1.0.0/router.go:866 +0x217
github.com/revel/revel.RevelHooks.Run({0xc000124680, 0x7, 0x8})
        C:/Users/User/go/pkg/mod/github.com/revel/revel@v1.0.0/revel_hooks.go:32 +0x18a
github.com/revel/revel.InitServer()
        C:/Users/User/go/pkg/mod/github.com/revel/revel@v1.0.0/server.go:39 +0x52
github.com/revel/revel.Run(0xdc7709?)
        C:/Users/User/go/pkg/mod/github.com/revel/revel@v1.0.0/server.go:81 +0x118
lfacturabackend/app/tmp/run.Run(0x0?)
        C:/Users/User/go/lfactura/lfacturabackend/app/tmp/run/run.go:27 +0x28
main.main()
        C:/Users/User/go/lfactura/lfacturabackend/app/tmp/main.go:24 +0x98
PS C:\Users\User\go\lfactura\testtarget>
```

Comment: please add code snippet

Answer (score 0):

well answer is simple. revel generates run.bat with following line

```
lfacturabackend.exe -importPath lfacturabackend -srcPath "%CD%\src" -runMode prod
```

Firstly i removed "-runMode prod" that caused "not found run mode prod" error.
And to fix error in my question i changed `-srcPath "%CD%\src"` to `-srcPath "src"`